# Javascript performance degredation warnings assigning attribute in loop

Tags: apex, lightning-aura-components, lightning, aura

I am fetching the data from apex class into Aura component controller and in callback action, i am doing

```
 var effectiveFromDate = "";

            var effectiveFromDateMonth = "";
            var effectiveToDateMonth = "";

            for (var i=0;i<contacts.length;i++) {

                effectiveFromDate = response.getReturnValue()[i].ServiceContact__r.EffectiveFromDate__c;


             effectiveFromDate = new Date(effectiveFromDate);
             effectiveFromDateMonth = effectiveFromDate.toString().split(" ")[1];
            // Months use 0 index.
            effectiveFromDate =  effectiveFromDateMonth+  ' ' + effectiveFromDate.getDate() + ',  ' + effectiveFromDate.getFullYear();

            component.set('v.listOfContacts[' + i + '].ServiceContact__r.EffectiveFromDate__c',effectiveFromDate); 


            }
```

So when i run this code it gives me warning, number of times this for loop runs.but the error goes when i comment

```
component.set('v.listOfContacts[' + i + '].ServiceContact__r.EffectiveFromDate__c',effectiveFromDate);
```

This is the warning:

> WARNING: Performance degradation: Multiple items were set in iteration in the same aura cycle

Can anyone help me on this? How to get rid of warnings?

Comment: What's the warning?

Comment: is this a performance degradation warning in console?

Comment: Yes, it is coming console. WARNING: Performance degradation: Multiple items were set in iteration in the same aura cycle.

Comment: What does your markup look like? Do you have a `ui:iteration` component where the `items` property is set to `v.listOfContacts`?

Comment: I figured out why it is coming, as i have one iteration in javascript function which is setting the attributes directly proportional to number of times loop runs.If i comment that "component.set" part warning disappears. But, unfortunately i can not comment that thing. @TrevorBliss please let me know if you still need to see code :) . Thanks in advance

Comment: No more code necessary. I added an answer below for a pattern you can try to follow to not only get rid of the warning, but improve the perf of your app.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The performance degradation warning happens when you update the aura:attribute that your `aura:iteration` is iterating over (the `items`  attribute) multiple times in the same cycle. Instead of calling `cmp.set()` inside your loop, try grabbing the attribute via `cmp.get()` and fully modify that object before setting it back on the markup.

Here's a simplified example. Try adapting this pattern to your code:

```
var items = cmp.get("v.listOfContacts");
for (var i = 0; i < contacts.length; i++) {
    items[i].data = contacts[i].data
}
cmp.set("v.listOfContacts", items);
```